# What is the searchIndex for clothing and accesories?

Tags: amazon-web-services

i'm trying to import some products through Amazon API,
Now, i'm in the middle of a problem, i'm using the ItemSearch operation, and i know i can mix the searchIndex and the keywords, and I know there is a list of valid Search index [SearchIndex list](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/USSearchIndexParamForItemsearch.html)
But my question is, how i can get the closest to looks like the ASINS of this url http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_1?rh=n%3A2475895011%2Ck%3Awallets+for+men&keywords=wallets+for+men&ie=UTF8&qid=1385709391&rnid=2941120011
As you can see, in this link, the breadcrumbs says:
Clothing & Accessories › Men › Accessories › Wallets, Card Cases & Money Organizers › Wallets › "wallets"

So, i don't see nothing in the SearchIndex to seems like "clothing and accesories"

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SearchIndex can be set as "Apparel"

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/SearchIndices.html